# Angular CLI production build doesn't load on Apache

Tags: apache, angular, ubuntu-16.04

I build my production build with `ng build --env=prod`. When I try to serve it with Apache 2 all I see is `Loading...`. No error messages in the console, nothing.

The weird thing is that:

1) The `development build` works just fine

2) Also the `production build` works fine with the dev server and also with e.g. a Python ad-hoc server.

What could possibly cause this?

I only set in my `environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
   production: true
};
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your web browser console?

Comment: I actually just figured this out...I had altered the `<base href="/">` after the build depending on prod/dev and it caused evil things. Any ideas how to set this correctly depending on build?